# Is it possible to identify the presence of server auth module programatically in glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jaspic, jsr196

I have enabled a server authentication module (JSR196) in Glassfish . The module works as expected however i need to determine the presence of the authentication module in a servlet programatically.

Is there any way i could check the presence of the authentication module using java ?

Answer (score 2):

Dexter meyers' [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32951376/3986374) should work just fine, provided that:

1. your application uses a single `ServerAuthModule` (SAM),
2. no AS-wide -i.e. having been registered with the `AuthConfigFactory` with `null appContext` and `"HttpServlet"` or `null layer` arguments- `AuthConfigProvider` has been established,
3. you do not provide your own `AuthConfigProvider`, `ServerAuthConfig` and `ServerAuthContext` implementations, and
4. your sole concern is to receive a runtime confirmation that the SAM has been "activated" for your application.

Otherwise, a non-`null` return from `AuthConfigFactory#getConfigProvider(String, String, RegistrationListener)` might be misleading, in the sense that it does not necessarily assert that your application uses a SAM, only that an `AuthConfigProvider` has been put into place at a compatible layer and *could* serve your application's authentication needs if the rest of the required components (`ServerAuthConfig` et al.) are registered as well.

If you additionally need to know which SAMs exactly your application has been configured to use, there is, afaik, no standard way to do so, as, first and foremost, `ServerAuthContext` does not expose its encapsulated SAMs (and its very acquisition via `ServerAuthConfig#getAuthContext(String, Subject, Map)` is not straightforward anyway, since JASPIC's Servlet Profile leaves *authContextID*s arbitrary). Which basically means you will either need to implement your own `ServerAuthContext` (along with the 2 further indirections) to get that functionality, or alternatively attach an identifier to represent the SAM to the `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpSession`, if it suffices for you to know which SAMs got triggered for individual requests. Note that in case you prefer to use the `javax.servlet.http.authType MessageInfo` callback property to set the value returned by `HttpServletRequest#getAuthType()` instead, it will only work when authentication succeeds, that is, when your SAM's `validateRequest(...)` establishes a non-`null` caller `Principal` and/or at least a single AS group `Principal` and returns `AuthStatus.SUCCESS`; otherwise you will get a `null` despite having set the callback property.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by checking for the `AuthConfigProvider`, which can be done via:

First define helper method:

```
String getAppContextID(ServletContext context)
 return context.getVirtualServerName() + " " + context.getContextPath();
}
```

Then call this code when the ServletContext is available, like in a `@WebListener`:

```
AuthConfigFactory factory = AuthConfigFactory.getFactory();

String appContextID = getAppContextID(context);

AuthConfigProvider provider = factory.getConfigProvider("HttpServlet", appContextID, null);
```